# How do I connect perceptrons to make a neural network?

Tags: python, perceptron

So, I was following [this nice tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/perceptron-and-its-implementation-in-python-f87d6c7aa428) about perceptrons in python. Of course, perceptrons can only work in binary classification problems, but if I join more perceptrons (one per class) then I can have a network where each perceptron identifies if the data belongs to each class.
My question is, if I have three classes, (1, 2, 3) then I know how to train the two "*extremes*" (if output is less or equal than 1 / greater or equal than 3), but I can't figure out how to train the "*middle*" one, other than adding an if with two conditions (greater than 1 and less than 3).
How is it done?

Comment: can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: You are looking at a very simplified perceptron tutorial. My opinion is that you would have to do a lot of math to get it up from a binary class to multiclass classifier. If you want to dive into the math, do it by hand and the 3 perceptron solution will pop up. If you do not want to dive into the math, I would recommend using a library made for neural nets and forget about all the math. Have a look at keras/pytorch. I recommend keras because its much easier to follow.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. you must use the one-to-all method. this is a link to get you started. https://utkuufuk.com/2018/06/03/one-vs-all-classification/

Comment: @JasonChia I think I got it, or at least where to go from here. Thank you

Comment: @moeassal That wasa  great place to start. Thank you